# Render a text only 1 time instead of 2 times in React Js ,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Hello i have this component which is simply showing a status

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useEntity } from '@backstage/plugin-catalog-react';

import { isArgoCDAvailable } from './utils/isArgoCDAvailable';
import { configApiRef, useApi } from '@backstage/core-plugin-api';
import { AppData } from './utils/types';

function ShowApplication({
  appName,
  applications,
  setApplications,
  factory,
  namespaces,
}: Props) {

  const getApplication = async () => {
    if (isArgoCDAvailable(entity)) {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${backendUrl}/api/sisalArgoCD/argoCD/application/${factory}`,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(namespaces),
        },
      );

      const payload = await response.json();

      setApplications(payload.applications);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {applications.map((application: AppData) => {
        return <p>{application.status.sync.status}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ShowApplication;
```

As you can see it's showing the status 'Synced' 2 times for each of the components, of course it does show because it's iterating and for each iteration it will render the status but i need to show the 'Synced' only once for each component it belongs to . Can someone help me and if you need more things to add just comment down here .
[image]

Also this is the code snipper of the parent that is rendering this components

```js
elements.push(
          <div style={{ margin: '10px 0px' }}>
            {/* use argocd-accordion class to style accordion */}
            <Accordion classes={{ root: 'argocd-accordion' }}>
              <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls={`panel${key}-content`}
                id={`panel${key}-header`}
              >
                <ShowApplication
                  appName={
                    key === 'dataProd'
                      ? 'Dataplatform Prod'
                      : 'Dataplatform Preprod'
                  }
                  applications={applications}
                  setApplications={setApplications}
                  factory={factory}
                  namespaces={namespaces}
                />
              </AccordionSummary>
              {deploymentsRow}
              {items}
            </Accordion>
          </div>,
        );
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `ShowApplication` implies it's supposed to show a single application. Why does it get a list of applications?

Comment: Is `ShowApplication` component supposed to deal with a single application?

Comment: I think you guys are both right , i’m passing the whole list which is my mistake and a very dumb mistake , yes it’s supposed to show only one application for every accordion , i mean for each respective accordion so i will try to do a refactor and see if that will solve it

Comment: Passing only a single application object didn't fix it . Because the problem stands on the second code snippet that i posted elements.push is rendering it many times